# Problem with SVD in Input Output model

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab, svd

Here is a problem I was looking at: Let production of Steel, Coal and electric power be $P_s, P_c$ and $P_e$ respectively. Their output (in column) and consumption (in row) are given:

$$
\begin{array}{|l|c|c|c|}
\hline
& Steel & Coal & Electricity \\
\hline
Steel & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.5 \\
Coal & 0.3 & 0.2 & 0.4 \\
Electricity & 0.6 & 0.7 & 0.1 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

To find equilibrium solution following system of equations is formed:

$$
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
-0.9 & 0.1 & 0.5 \\
0.3 & -0.8 & 0.4 \\
0.6 & 0.7 & -0.9
\end{pmatrix}}_A
\begin{pmatrix}
P_s \\ P_c \\ P_e
\end{pmatrix}
=
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}}_b
$$

Neither of $P=A^{-1}b$ and $P=A^+b$ works, so they've come up with SVD to produce a solution. To find $A=U\Sigma V^T$ following code is used:

```
A = [-0.9  0.1  0.5; 
      0.3 -0.8  0.4; 
      0.6  0.7 -0.9];

sigma1 = A*A'; sigma2 = A'*A;
U = eye(3); V = eye(3);

for i = 1:15
    [Q1,R1] = qr(sigma1);
    [Q2,R2] = qr(sigma2);
    U  = U * Q1; sigma1 = R1 * Q1;
    V  = V * Q2; sigma2 = R2 * Q2;
end

S = diag(diag(sigma1)); S = sqrt(S);
U = round(U,5); Sigma = round(S,5); V = round(V,5);
```

With these $U,\Sigma$ and $V$ I get $U\Sigma V^T=-A$. To get correct result I've to multiply $V$ or $U$ by $-1$. With 15 iteration $U,\Sigma$ and $V$ are:

$$
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
 -0.4852 &  0.6567 &  0.5774 \\
 -0.3262 & -0.7485 &  0.5774 \\
  0.8113 &  0.0918 &  0.5774 
 \end{pmatrix}}_U\:
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
 1.5836 & & \\
 & 1.0547 & \\
 & & 0
 \end{pmatrix}}_{\Sigma}\:
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
   -0.5214 &  0.7211 &  0.4563 \\
 -0.4928 & -0.6910 &  0.5289 \\
  0.6967 &  0.0509 &  0.7156 \end{pmatrix}}_V
$$ 
If I change **for i = 1:15**  to **for i = 1:115**  and type U, Sigma and V in command window I get same thing but when I multiply $U\Sigma V^T$ I get:

$$
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
 0.9000  & -0.1000 &  -0.5000 \\
   -0.3000  &  0.8000 &  -0.4000 \\
   -0.6000  & -0.7000  &  0.9000 
 \end{pmatrix}}_{\texttt{for i = 1:15}}\quad\quad
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
 -0.0989  &  0.8572 &  -0.5705 \\
0.8385 &  -0.2910  & -0.3197 \\
   -0.7396  & -0.5662   & 0.8901 \end{pmatrix}}_{\texttt{for i = 1:115}}
$$

**Q1:** What is the problem?

To find a solution last column of $V$ is chosen and normalized:
$$
P=
\frac{1}{0.7156}
\begin{pmatrix}
  0.4563 \\
  0.5289 \\
  0.7156 
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
  0.6377 \\
  0.7391 \\
  1.0000
\end{pmatrix}
$$

**Q2:** Why to choose last column of $V$?

**Q3:** Can I get same solution using $U$?

**Q4:** It is not unique and not least-square solution, What it is?

Comment: @Moo Can it be solved by Gaussian Elimination? If I use rational numbers, results are same. How to use infinite precision?

Comment: @Moo, Here [Gaussian Elimination](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=rref+%7B%7B-.9,+.1,+.5%7D,%7B.3,+-.8,+.4%7D,+%7B.6,+.7,+-.9%7D%7D) probably they have used Eigenvalue Decomposition. SVD is similar to that.

Comment: Instead of doing it one by one by hand, you should use elementary matrices for multiple row operation in a single shot, that is easier. @Moo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar conundrum is discussed here: [Query about the Moore Penrose pseudoinverse method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1800457/query-about-the-moore-penrose-pseudoinverse-method/2200546#2200546). On to your question.

### Existence

Given the matrix 
$$
\mathbf{A} = \frac{1}{10}
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr}
 -9 & 1 & 5 \\
 3 & -2 & 4 \\
 6 & 7 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
and the data vector
$$
b
=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 0 \\
 0 \\
 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]  
$$
what can we say about the linear system
$$
\mathbf{A} x = b?
$$

Using Gauss-Jordan elimination,
$$
\begin{align}
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 \mathbf{A} & \mathbf{I}_{3}
\end{array}
\right]  
%
&\mapsto
%
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 \mathbf{E_{A}} & \mathbf{R}
\end{array}
\right]  \\
%%
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr|ccc}
 -\frac{9}{10} &  \frac{1}{10} &  \frac{1}{2}  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  \frac{3}{10} & -\frac{1}{5}  &  \frac{2}{5}  & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  \frac{3}{5}  & \frac{7}{10}  & -\frac{1}{10} & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
&\mapsto
%
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|rrr}
 1 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{130}{213} & \frac{60}{71} & \frac{70}{213} \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{45}{71} & -\frac{35}{71} & \frac{85}{71} \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{55}{71} & \frac{115}{71} & \frac{25}{71} \\
\end{array}
\right]
\tag{1}
%
\end{align}
$$

Conclusion:
All columns are fundamental. The matrix has full rank. The nullspace is trivial: 
$$\mathcal{N}\left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)=\emptyset$$

A nontrivial solution to the homogeneous equation *does not exist.* Solving the equation $\mathbf{A}x=\mathbf{0}$ is tantamount to asking for a vector in the nullspace. There are no such nontrivial vectors.

The existence drum is beaten often and loudly here on MSE:

[Exact solution of overdetermined linear system](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2244851/exact-solution-of-overdetermined-linear-system/2261603#2261603)

[Existence of least squares solution to Ax=b](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72222/existence-of-least-squares-solution-to-ax-b/2209584#2209584)

[Unique least square solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/901484/unique-least-square-solutions/2170702#2170702)

[Is a least squares solution to $Ax=b$ necessarily unique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1718183/is-a-least-squares-solution-to-ax-b-necessarily-unique)

[Let $A$ be an 8 x 5 matrix of rank 3, and let $b$ be a nonzero vector in $N(A^{})$. Show $Ax=b$ must be inconsistent.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1523698/let-a-be-an-8-x-5-matrix-of-rank-3-and-let-b-be-a-nonzero-vector-in-nat/2181215#2181215)

[null space of a matrix for a matrix with a 0 column](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2264764/null-space-of-a-matrix-for-a-matrix-with-a-0-column/2264771#2264771)

[Why does $A^{T}Ax=A^{T}b$ have infinitely many solution algebraically when $A$ has dependent columns?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2262225/why-does-atax-atb-have-infinitely-many-solution-algebraically-when-a-has/2262432#2262432)

[Will 2 linear equations with 2 unknowns always have a solution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2269220/will-2-linear-equations-with-2-unknowns-always-have-a-solution/2269269#2269269)

[When does the least squares solution exist?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1480125/moore-penrose-inverse-as-least-squares-solution/2223158#2223158)

### SVD

$$
 \mathbf{A} =
  \mathbf{U} \, \mathbf{S} \, \mathbf{V}^{*} 
\tag{2}
$$

To clear up confusion of building the SVD, the steps are detailed.

1. Construct the product matrix $\mathbf{A}^{*} \mathbf{A}$.
2. Resolve eigensystem of product matrix: Construct $S$, $V$.
3. Using $(2)$, construct $\mathbf{U} = \mathbf{A} \mathbf{V} \mathbf{S}^{-1}$.

**1 Product matrix**

$$
\mathbf{A}^{*} \mathbf{A} =
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr}
 1.26 & 0.27 & -0.39 \\
 0.27 & 0.54 & -0.10 \\
 -0.39 & -0.10 & 0.42 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

**2 Eigensystem decomposition**

Eigenvalues:
$$
 \lambda \left( \mathbf{A}^{*}\mathbf{A} \right) =
\left\{
  1.49952 , 0.453789 , 0.266694
\right\}
$$
The singular values are computed using
$$
 \sigma = \lambda \left( \mathbf{A}^{*}\mathbf{A} \right)
$$
Construct the $\mathbf{S}$ matrix:
$$
 \mathbf{S} =
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1.22455 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0.673639 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0.516425 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Eigenvectors:
$$
v_{1} = 
\left[
\begin{array}{l}
 -0.892021  \\
 -0.287368 \\
 \phantom{-}0.348883 \\
\end{array}
\right], \quad
%
v_{2} = 
\left[
\begin{array}{l}
 \phantom{-} 0.256905 \\
 -0.957414 \\
 -0.131749
\end{array}
\right], \quad
%
v_{3} = 
\left[
\begin{array}{l}
 \phantom{-} 0.371886 \\
 -0.0278925 \\
\phantom{-}  0.927859 
\end{array}
\right]
%
$$
Construct the matrix $\mathbf{V}$, an orthonormal span for the row space:
$$
 \mathbf{V} =
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{v_{1}}{\lVert v_{1} \rVert} & 
 \frac{v_{1}}{\lVert v_{2} \rVert} &
 \frac{v_{1}}{\lVert v_{3} \rVert}
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{lll}
 -0.892021 & \phantom{-}0.256905 & \phantom{-}0.371886 \\
 -0.287368 & -0.957414 & -0.0278925 \\
 \phantom{-}0.348883 & -0.131749 & \phantom{-}0.927859 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

**3 Column space matrix**

$$
\mathbf{U} = \mathbf{A} \mathbf{V} \mathbf{S}^{-1} =
\left[
\begin{array}{llc}
 \phantom{-}0.774591 & -0.583147 & 0.244844 \\
 -0.0576372 & \phantom{-}0.320431 & 0.945517 \\
 -0.629831 & -0.746501 & 0.214592 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

### Moore-Penrose Pseudoinverse

The pseudoinverse is easily assembled using the SVD decomposition matrices.

$$
 \mathbf{A}^{+} =
  \mathbf{V} \, \mathbf{S}^{-1} \, \mathbf{U}^{*} =
\left[
\begin{array}{llc}
 -0.610329 & \phantom{-}0.84507 & 0.328638 \\
 \phantom{-}0.633803 & -0.492958 & 1.19718 \\
 \phantom{-}0.774648 & \phantom{-}1.61972 & 0.352113 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\tag{2}
$$